# How does one find out if a computer can run either a 32 or 64-bit OS, without an OS being installed on it?

Tags: bios, operating-systems

**See title.**

I am trying to figure out if it's possible for someone to find the proper information without an OS being on the machine in question. Usually there are a number of programs you could use to find whether your computer can use either/or, and in the case of Windows it tells you if your machine is 64-bit compatible.

However, I do not have an OS installed on this machine, and from my knowledge you cannot run an executable without an OS. Do I use the BIOS? Determine it by RAM? 'How do?'

Thanks in advance, and pardon my computer illiteracy.

Comment: Unless this PC is a custom built PC, you could always check the manufacturer website for the make and model and look up the system specs and that is a way to tell.  Some setting in the BIOS may indicate whether or not it's x64 or x86 as well. If the tower, etc. has a processor sticker on it, that too may be an indicator. Otherwise, you could look up the serial number on the motherboard I suppose and that'd maybe tell you, or boot to a Linux Live OS and check. There are probably all sorts of ways to do this and that's a few of them for identifying the CPU architecture on your computer hardware.

Comment: Ah! A live OS would do the trick. The machine in question is a laptop with no sticker or anything of the like, though I do believe I've found the answer by checking the BIOS for the CPU model, and checking manufacturer information through that.

Answer (score -1):

The only way to know if machine is 64/32bit without running any OS is to find out the model of the processor and look up information about it on internet.
You can find information about CPU in BIOS (as outlined in Method 4 [here](http://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1009755)), you can also open the machine up, remove heatsink (if that is possible) and look up what it says on the processor.
If you can install/run OS on this machine then you can simply do that and check it from there.
If you do not want to go into lengthy process of installing OS (especially Windows), simply download some lightweight Linux distribution [from here](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/live-cd-repository/) and run it from usb/cd.
**Make sure you download 32 bit version as it will run on both 32 and 64 systems.**
In Linux open the terminal and type in:

> getconf LONG_BIT

The answer will be either 64 or 32.